# What are top level objects?

Tags: iphone, nib

What are top level objects in an iPhone application nib file?

Comment: If you open a xib in Interface Builder it'll show you...

Comment: Are the two NARQ votes cast because of the "please answer" part? I can't really tell otherwise.

Comment: @boltclock...I had a confusion...file owner and first reponder are definitely not top level objects...is the view object??
thats what i wanted to know...

Answer (score 1):

About the Top-Level Objects

When your program loads a nib file, Cocoa recreates the entire graph of objects you created in Xcode. This object graph includes all of the windows, views, controls, cells, menus, and custom objects found in the nib file. The top-level objects are the subset of these objects that do not have a parent object. **The top-level objects typically include only the windows, menu bars, and custom controller objects** that you add to the nib file. (Objects such as File’s Owner, First Responder, and Application are placeholder objects and not considered top-level objects.)

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html